# When I am passing data in my SQL query through postman it is returning "undefined" for all the three fields

Tags: sql, node.js

```
module.exports.restinfo = function (restdetail, callback) {
    sql.connect(db_config, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sql.close();
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            var createrest = "'INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_childdetails(Division,FirstName,LastName)VALUES" + "(" + restdetail.division + "," + restdetail.firstname + "," + restdetail.lastname + ")";
            console.log(createrest);
            request.query(createrest, function (err, recordset) {
                if (err) {
                    callback('Error', null);
                } else {
                    callback(null, 'Success');
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Result being returned is:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_childdetails (Division, FirstName, LastName) 
VALUES (undefined, undefined, undefined)

ErrorErrorResult : null

router.post('/childrest', function (req, res) {
var restdetail = {
    "division": req.body.section,
    "firstname": req.body.fn,
    "lastname": req.body.ln
};
dbops.restinfo(restdetail, function (err, result) {
    console.log("Error" + err + "Result:" + result);
    res.send("Done");
});
});
```

Comment: restdetail is undefined, obviously, can you include the calling of restinfo?

Comment: ok lemme check @MattKuhns

Comment: i have posted that restinfo plz help me

Comment: var restdetail = {
    "division": "section",
    "firstname": "fn",
    "lastname": "ln"
}; 
Try to do this in the calling function, do the values come through?

Comment: ok let me try matt

Comment: i had added req.body because i am using postman to insert data

Comment: yes, but simplifiy this. perhaps your req.body is not set correctly. Hard code the object and see if that gets passed through.

Comment: i will let you knkw if it works or not plz be in touch

Comment: yeah i tried it when hardcoded it is taking values @MattKuhns

Comment: when i am using req.body it is showing undefined please help me to solve this

Comment: Are you using bodyParser?      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: yeah thanku...i did that i checked that i was not using body parser when i install npm install body-parser --save it worked thanku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use bodyParser.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```